# SimpMessageHeaderAccessor#getUser is nullable after upgrade to spring-boot-2. How to handle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

Source code under question:

```
@Configuration
public class PresenceEventListener {    
    @EventListener
    public void handleSessionConnected(SessionConnectEvent event) {
        SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headers = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
        Principal principal = headers.getUser();
        /* custom logic with principal.getName() */
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleSessionDisconnect(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headers = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
        Principal principal = headers.getUser();
        /* custom logic with principal.getName() */
    }
}
```

This code is more or less identical in all examples I could find.
[Here's one reference...](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sergialmar/wschat/event/PresenceEventListener.java#L36)

By upgrading from spring-boot v1.5 to v2, Findbugs complains about `.getName()` because `principal` might be `null`, and is unchecked.

This is because spring-messaging, since v5, has marked method [SimpMessageHeaderAccessor#getUser](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.java#L177) as `@Nullable`.

My question is how is this supposed to be handled properly? (i.e. when `#getUser` returns `null`)
Should the code throw an exception? do nothing?
And what does it actually mean that the user is `null` in this context?
Could this be considered a hacking attempt ?

```
Principal principal = headers.getUser();
if (principal == null) {
    // what should happen here ?
}
```

Thanks !